# How to iterate over associative array keys indirectly?

Tags: bash, associative-array

I am writing a script that reads a number of variables in from a config file. A number of those variables are associative arrays. One or more of those hashes need to be parsed at runtime in order to set a number of session related parameters.

While I can access values for each key individually like this:

```
declare -A "$1"

. /path-to-config/script.conf

_hashid=$1
param=${_hashid_}[string]
echo ${!param}
```

I am unable to access the keys themselves. What I'd like to do is something like this:

```
declare -A "$1"

. /path-to-config/script.conf

_hashref_=${1}[@]
for key in "${!_hashref_}" ; do
   echo ${_hashref_[$key]}
done
```

This sets `$key` to the value of each element. And other variations I've tried on it haven't worked either. Can someone explain to me how to iterate over the keys when the hash name is dynamic?

Comment: I've tried this too. Since the `!` syntax is overloaded here, I don't think there is a way. I believe this is a limitation of the shell.